# Efficient way to test availability of android location service and how to test it?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am developing an android app that uses the location services. From the documentation given [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html), I understand that location services is part of google play services apk.

My queries are:

1.Is it necessary to test the availability of google play services before I use the   location services, or can I directly test by checking if the location manager returned is null using the code below.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Which of these approaches would be efficient?

2.How likely is it for the play services to be unavailable anytime?

3.If I need to test if the google play services is available or not,
 how do I safely simulate the unavailability behaviour of the google
 play services apk on my device, in order to test my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it may help you see my ans...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it is always good to check whether google play services are available in a device and if not then prompt to install it which will handle your condition 3 exactly.And once you have installed that in your device,there are no possibility to unavailable it, and if unavailable for any reason, then again that check will prompt you to install it, so you needn't to think about it which fulfill your condition 2.

And for condition 1, i would like to say, first check availability of google play services and then check location services as like your above code.
So let's check how to check availability of google play services:

```
// Getting status
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    // Showing status
    if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
        tvStatus.setText("Google Play Services are available");  //success message
    else
    {
        tvStatus.setText("Google Play Services are not available");  // not success
        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();   //this will prompt to install
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ridoy. I would like to test the condition 3 either on emulator or my android device. Is there a way to make the play services unavailable on emulator? Or safely on android device? I would prefer to experiment this on an emulator.

Comment: In my opinion, it is not wise to test that kind of services in an emulator because that result may vary from real world.If possible, try to test that on a real device.